# Who were the three dead Riddles?

Tags: harry-potter

I was reading *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire* and in the first chapter I read that three Riddles were killed in the Riddle House.

> Every version of the tale, however, started in the same place: fifty years before, at daybreak on a fine summer's morning, when the the Riddle House had still been well kept and impressive, and a maid had entered the drawing room to find all three Riddles dead.
>   <sub>*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, chapter 1: "The Riddle House"</sub>

Who were these people, and how they were related to Voldemort?

Comment: I'm thinking the maid was lucky she wasn't there when the curses went a-flying.

Answer (score 40):

Voldemort's father and grandparents.

> Elderly Mr. and Mrs. Riddle had been rich, snobby, and rude, and their grown up son, Tom, had been, if anything, worse.
>   <sub>*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, chapter 1: "The Riddle House"</sub>

> Voldemort laughed again. Up and down he paced, looking all around him as he walked, and the snake continued to circle in the grass.
>   "You see that house upon the hillside, Potter? My father lived there. My mother, a witch who lived here in this village, fell in love with him. But he abandoned her when she told him what she was.... He didn't like magic, my father...
>   "He left her and returned to his Muggle parents before I was even born, Potter, and she died giving birth to me, leaving me to be raised in a Muggle village... but I vowed to find him... I revenged myself upon him, that fool who gave me his name... Tom Riddle...."
>
> Still he paced, his red eyes darting from grave to grave.
>
> "Listen to me, reliving family history...." he said quietly, "why, I am growing quite sentimental... But look, Harry! My true family returns..."
>
> The air was suddenly full of the swishing of cloaks.
>   <sub>*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, chapter 33: "The Death Eaters"</sub>

Comment: Ah, beat me by a minute. :)

Answer (score 38):

### They were Voldemort's father and grandparents

It's explained in a following book that Voldemort killed his father and grandparents, whilst making it seem (to the Ministry) that it was his uncle Morfin who did the deed. (Emphasis mine)

> “Meanwhile, in the village of Little Hangleton, a maid was running along the High Street,
>   screaming that there were **three bodies** lying in the drawing room of the big house: Tom Riddle
>   Senior and his mother and father.
>
> “The Muggle authorities were perplexed. As far as I am aware, they do not know to this day how
>   the Riddles died, for the Avada Kedavra curse does not usually leave any sign of damage…
>
> *[...]*
>
> “So Voldemort stole Morfin’s wand and used it?” said Harry, sitting up straight.
>
> “That’s right,” said Dumbledore. “We have no memories to show us this, but I think we can be
>   fairly sure what happened. Voldemort Stupefied his uncle, took his wand, and proceeded across
>   the valley to ‘the big house over the way.’ **There he murdered the Muggle man who had
>   abandoned his witch mother, and, for good measure, his Muggle grandparents, thus obliterating
>   the last of the unworthy Riddle line and revenging himself upon the father who never wanted
>   him**. Then he returned to the Gaunt hovel, performed the complex bit of magic that would
>   implant a false memory in his uncle’s mind, laid Morfin’s wand beside its unconscious owner,
>   pocketed the ancient ring he wore, and departed.”
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, Chapter 17</sub>